# VS code indentation mode changes from spaces to tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I am using VS code with a number of extensions, including pylance , editorconfig, prettier, . No matter how many times I change the insertSpaces to true for the different languages or any indentation related settings to spaces  mode, at some point (sometimes after a couple of minutes of usage, sometimes after reopening VS code) the tab key starts indenting with tab.  I notice this mostly by  pressing enter. How can I figure out which extension is doing   overriding the spaces indentation mode? I don't want to go through the exercise of testing them one by one. Here's my settings.json that I have pruned down  to remove nonrelevant settings.

```
{
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    //"shellformat.useEditorConfig": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 10,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.codeLens": true,
    // Generic
    "cSpell.enabled": true,
    "cSpell.language": "en",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0303",
        "--indent-string=\"    \""
    ],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    },
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.convention": "Hint",
    "python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.refactor": "Warning",
    "python.linting.maxNumberOfProblems": 200,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": [
        "--max-line-length=100"
    ],
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "vsintellicode.python.completionsEnabled": true,
    "[json]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true
    },
    // R
    "[r]": {
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Ikuyadeu.r",
        "editor.comments.insertSpace": true,
    },
    "r.interpreter": 0,
    "r.linting.enable": true,
    "r.lsp.debug": true,
    "r.linting.maxLineLength": 105,
    "r.editor.tabSize": 2,
    "r.linting.noTabs": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.comments.insertSpace": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": false,
    "editor.useTabStops": true,
    "editor.stickyTabStops": false,
    "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    // REMOTE connection
    "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true,
    "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": true,
    "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
    "search.showLineNumbers": true,
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": false,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "material-icon-theme.showUpdateMessage": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 3,
    "sync.removeExtensions": true,
    "sync.syncExtensions": true,
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [],
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.workspaceSymbols.enabled": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.languageServer": "None",
    "gitlens.currentLine.enabled": false,
    "gitlens.hovers.currentLine.over": "line",
    "gitlens.statusBar.enabled": false,
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "[ignore]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "foxundermoon.shell-format"
    },
    "editor.autoIndent": "brackets",
    "formattingToggle.affects": [
        "editor.formatOnPaste",
        "editor.formatOnSave",
        "editor.formatOnType"
    ],
  
}
```

Comment: You need to be more careful when analyzing VS Code behavior, because there are tons of factors determining what takes effect and what overrides. "I don't want to go through the exercise of testing them one by one" is not the attitude to go if you do want a solution. How can anyone here to help when they actually have no access to your setup?

Comment: if you disable all extensions and the problem is gone, you have to find the culprit yourself